# Moving duplicates into a new column

Tags: r, excel, formatting

I've got this two column database that lists gene codes and then biological pathway. Within the database some gene codes are linked to multiple biological pathways:

```
      A           B
    396139  mesonephros development    
    396139  camera-type eye development  
    396139  Sertoli celldevelopment
```

I'm trying to get rid of these repeats, while moving each biological function to a new column:

```
  A       B                         C                           D
396139    mesonephros development   camera-type eye development Sertoli celldevelopment
```

I've tried a few macros in Excel, but have been unsuccessful in making anything constructive. I'm also a little new to R so I have no idea where I would start to format this. Any help in either software would be much appreciated.

This question is different from the claimed duplicate because they are trying to combine columns when I require them to be separate. The answer in this question is also simpler and does not require an external package and is, therefore, worth keeping separate.

Comment: Can you share the excel macro you tried?

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed. It wasn't doing anything, Let me try to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Gened.Code', we `paste` the elements in 'Organ.Developmental.Effect' together.  The `toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=', ')`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Col= toString(Organ.Developmental.Effect)) , Gene.Code]
#   Gene.Code
#1:        11
#2:        19
#3:        37
#4:       674
#5:      2033
#6:     2-Sep
#7:     5-Sep
#8:    396139
#                                                                             Col
#1:                                        eye photoreceptor cell differentiation
#2:                                        eye photoreceptor cell differentiation
#3:                                        eye photoreceptor cell differentiation
#4:                                           larval salivary gland morphogenesis
#5:                                                    compound eye morphogenesis
#6:                                                     imaginal disc development
#7:                                                     imaginal disc development
#8: metanephros development, mesonephros development, camera-type eye development
```

Comment: I got an error:   Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(DevAmigo), , list(biolpwy = paste(biolpwy,  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (1,1). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (10000).

Comment: @ephackett You mentioned two columns in the dataset, right.  So, I assumed the `geneid` is the first column

Comment: I changed it to the data.frame[1] in that section. Should I rename the column and attach the column names?

Comment: @ephackett Can you show the `dput` of the first few rows, ie. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdataset, 10)))`

Comment: Sure thing: structure(list(Gene.Code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("11", "19", "2-Sep", "2033", "37", 
"396139", "5-Sep", "674"), class = "factor"), Organ.Developmental.Effect = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("camera-type eye development", 
"compound eye morphogenesis", "eye photoreceptor cell differentiation", 
"imaginal disc development", "larval salivary gland morphogenesis", 
"mesonephros development", "metanephros development"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene.Code", 
"Organ.Developmental.Effect"),

Comment: @ephackett I think it is not the full output.  Can you update your post with the dput output.

Comment: structure(list(Gene.Code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 
7L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("11", "19", "2-Sep", "2033", "37", 
"396139", "5-Sep", "674"), class = "factor"), Organ.Developmental.Effect = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("camera-type eye development", 
"compound eye morphogenesis", "eye photoreceptor cell differentiation", 
"imaginal disc development", "larval salivary gland morphogenesis", 
"mesonephros development", "metanephros development"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Gene.Code", 
"Organ.Developmental.Effect") (1/2)

Comment: , row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000150788>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")) (2/2)

Comment: @ephackett It is working for me

Comment: It did! Thanks so much for your patience with a R newbie!